# System Update for Windows 10 Pro Machine

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-pro

Machines are using Windows 10 Pro. Windows 10 Pro also requires users to perform Windows Updates. Windows update was disabled as machines need to function all day long. Should we still perform windows update manually and periodically, for example, every 3 months? Or is ok to left the windows update disabled without further update permanently?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of manually installing Windows updates you can use automated installation of Windows updates but prevent Windows from automatically reboot. 
There is this tiny tool called [Reboot Blocker](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_10_reboot_blocker.html) which adjusts the "work hours" every hour so that Windows update is not allowed to reboot the system.

Comment: Hi thanks, is it possible to schedule Windows updates automatically, I have a lot of machines deployed.

Comment: @WeiChenChen - Yes; There are tools that you deploy cumulative updates on your schedule.